# Using substrings properly in an if else statement java

Tags: java, logic

I am wondering if my logic and syntax makes sense with this if else statement? Do all of my if statements make sense when looking at syntax? I am trying to take the first two numbers of rentalDate to determine the month and see which season charge they will get. Thanks!

public double determinePrice () {

```
    double price;

    if (rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("01") || rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("02"))
    {
        price = WINTER_CHARGE;
    }
    else if (rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("12"))
    {
        price = WINTER_CHARGE;
    }
    else if (rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("03") || rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("04") || rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("05"))
    {
        price = SPRING_CHARGE;
    }
    else if (rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("06") || rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("07") || rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("08"))
    {
        price = SUMMER_CHARGE;
    }
    else
    {
        price = FALL_CHARGE;
    }

    return price;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't make sense. You're comparing the strings using *reference equality*, which is a common mistake when new to Java.

You should change all of your statements to use the `.equals()` method. This will compare the *values* of the Strings, as opposed to the values of the *references*, which you can also think of as "pointers" if you're coming from a C/C++ background.

So essentially, this:

```
rentalDate.substring(0,2) == ("01")
```

becomes...

```
"01".equals(rentalDate.substring(0,2))
```

You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/88111

Answer (score 0):

I would use a switch after parsing the month:

```
// can throw NumberformatException
int rentalMonthInt = Integer.parseInt(rentalDate.substring(0,2));

switch(rentalMonthInt){
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 12:
        return WINTER_CHARGE;
    // add more groups...
    default:
        System.out.err("month out of range..." + rentalMonthInt);
        // handle bad month
}
```

Note that cases for 1, 2 and 12 are executing the same code since there are no instructions or `break`s in any of them before the last. You can group months this way.

Comment: Good answer - my only critique would be to group the months together, so that `case 1:`, `case 2:`, and `case 12:` all result in the same codeblock, `// december, january, or february`

Comment: @CraigOtis I'm parsing his ranges, I'm not good with seasons. I'll just post an example.